# Upload an image online with NativeScript

Tags: upload, nativescript

I am developping a Nativscript-Vue mobile app, and I need to be able to select a file from the image gallery and upload it to an online file manager (I use 000webhost.com).

I worked with a code sample I got from the NativeScript website, and I am able to get the picture without problems, but I can't manage to upload it to WebHost (the logs says that the upload is successful, and there's no error showing up, but my pictures folder remains empty for some reason).

Here's my code :

```
    <template>
    <Page class="page">
        <ActionBar title="imagepicker + background-http" class="action-bar"></ActionBar>

        <GridLayout rows="*, auto">
            <GridLayout v-if="!showWelcome" rows="auto auto auto, *">
                <Progress :value="event && event.eventData ? event.eventData.currentBytes : 0"
                    :maxValue="event && event.eventData ? event.eventData.totalBytes : 0">
                </Progress>

                <Label row="1" v-if="event && event.eventData && event.eventData.currentBytes !== NaN"
                    class="m-10 text" :text="'Transferred: ' + event.eventData.currentBytes / 1000 + ' KB'"></Label>

                <Label row="2" class="m-10 text" text="Events"></Label>

                <ListView row="3" for="item in eventLog">
                    <v-template>
                        <StackLayout class="t-12">
                            <Label :text="item.eventTitle" textWrap="true"></Label>
                            <Label v-if="item.eventData && item.eventData.error"
                                :text="item.eventData ? 'Error: ' + item.eventData.error : ''"
                                textWrap="true"></Label>
                            <Label v-if="item.eventData && item.eventData.body"
                                :text="item.eventData ? 'Body: ' + item.eventData.body : ''"
                                textWrap="true"></Label>
                            <Label v-if="item.eventData && item.eventData.raw"
                                :text="item.eventData ? 'Raw: ' + item.eventData.raw : ''"
                                textWrap="true"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </v-template>
                </ListView>
            </GridLayout>
            <StackLayout v-if="showWelcome" verticalAlignment="middle">
                <Label class="m-10 nativescript-label text" text="{N}"></Label>
                <Label class="m-10 text" v-if="showWelcome" text="This sample app shows how to pick an image with"
                    textWrap="true"></Label>
                <Label class="m-10 text plugin" text="nativescript-imagepicker"></Label>
                <Label class="m-10 text" v-if="showWelcome" text="and upload it using"
                    textWrap="true"></Label>
                <Label class="m-10 text plugin" text="nativescript-background-http"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <Button class="m-b-10 m-t-10 t-20" row="1" text="Choose image to upload" @tap="onSelectImageTap($event)"></Button>
        </GridLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    import VueRx from "../vue-rx";
    import Vue from "nativescript-vue";

    const app = require("tns-core-modules/application");
    const platform = require("platform");
    const fs = require("file-system");
    const imagePicker = require("nativescript-imagepicker");
    const rxjs = require("rxjs");
    const operators = require("rxjs/operators");
    const bgHttp = require("nativescript-background-http");

    Vue.use(VueRx);
    // Vue.config.silent = false; // uncomment for debugging purposes

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                showWelcome: true,
                session: bgHttp.session("image-upload"),
                currentFileNameBeingUploaded: ""
            };
        },
        subscriptions() {
            this.event$ = new rxjs.BehaviorSubject({});
            return {
                event: this.event$,
                eventLog: this.event$.pipe(
                    operators.sampleTime(200),
                    operators.concatMap(value => rxjs.of(value)),
                    operators.scan((acc, logEntry) => {
                        acc.push(logEntry);
                        return acc;
                    }, []),
                    // emit only logs for the this.currentFileNameBeingUploaded
                    operators.map(allLogs => allLogs.filter(logEntry => !!logEntry && logEntry.eventTitle && logEntry.eventTitle.indexOf(this.currentFileNameBeingUploaded) > 0))
                )
            };
        },
        methods: {
            onSelectImageTap() {
                let context = imagePicker.create({
                    mode: "single"
                });
                this.startSelection(context);
            },
            startSelection(context) {
                context
                    .authorize()
                    .then(() => {
                        return context.present();
                    })
                    .then(selection => {
                        this.showWelcome = false;

                        let imageAsset = selection.length > 0 ? selection[
                            0] : null;
                        if (imageAsset) {
                            this.getImageFilePath(imageAsset).then(path => {
                                console.log(`path: ${path}`);
                                this.uploadImage(path);
                            });
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function(e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    });
            },
            uploadImage(path) {
                let file = fs.File.fromPath(path);
                this.currentFileNameBeingUploaded = file.path.substr(
                    file.path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1
                );
                let request = this.createNewRequest();
                request.description = "uploading image " + file.path;
                request.headers["File-Name"] = this.currentFileNameBeingUploaded;

                // -----> multipart upload
                // var params = [{
                //         name: "test",
                //         value: "value"
                //     },
                //     {
                //         name: "fileToUpload",
                //         filename: file.path,
                //         mimeType: "image/jpeg"
                //     }
                // ];
                // var task = this.session.multipartUpload(params, request);
                // <----- multipart upload

                let task = this.session.uploadFile(file.path, request);
                task.on("progress", this.onEvent.bind(this));
                task.on("error", this.onEvent.bind(this));
                task.on("responded", this.onEvent.bind(this));
                task.on("complete", this.onEvent.bind(this));
            },
            createNewRequest() {
                let url;
                // NOTE: using https://httpbin.org/post for testing purposes,
                // you'll need to use your own service in real-world app
                if (platform.isIOS) {
                    url = "https://ipaccovoiturage.000webhostapp.com/pictures";
                } else {
                    url = "https://ipaccovoiturage.000webhostapp.com/pictures";
                }

                let request = {
                    url: url,
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
                    },
                    description: "uploading file...",
                    androidAutoDeleteAfterUpload: false,
                    androidNotificationTitle: "NativeScript HTTP background"
                };
                return request;
            },
            getImageFilePath(imageAsset) {
                return new Promise(resolve => {
                    if (platform.isIOS) {
                        const options = PHImageRequestOptions.new();
                        options.synchronous = true;
                        options.version =
                            PHImageRequestOptionsVersion.Current;
                        options.deliveryMode =
                            PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.HighQualityFormat;

                        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAssetOptionsResultHandler(
                            imageAsset.ios,
                            options,
                            nsData => {
                                // create file from image asset and return its path
                                const tempFolderPath = fs.knownFolders
                                    .temp()
                                    .getFolder("nsimagepicker").path;
                                const tempFilePath = fs.path.join(
                                    tempFolderPath,
                                    Date.now() + ".jpg"
                                );

                                nsData.writeToFileAtomically(
                                    tempFilePath, true);
                                resolve(tempFilePath);
                            }
                        );
                    } else {
                        // return imageAsset.android, since it 's the path of the file
                        resolve(imageAsset.android);
                    }
                });
            },
            onEvent(e) {
                let eventEntry = {
                    eventTitle: e.eventName + " " + e.object.description,
                    eventData: {
                        error: e.error ? e.error.toString() : e.error,
                        currentBytes: e.currentBytes,
                        totalBytes: e.totalBytes,
                        body: e.data
                        // raw: JSON.stringify(e) // uncomment for debugging purposes
                    }
                };

                this.event$.next(eventEntry);
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<style scoped>
    .home-panel {
        vertical-align: center;
        font-size: 20;
        margin: 15;
    }

    .description-label {
        margin-bottom: 15;
    }

    .text {
        text-align:
            center;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .plugin {
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 23px;
    }

    .nativescript-label {
        font-size: 60px;
        background-color: #3d5afe;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 20px/20px;
        width: 230px;
        height: 230px;
    }
</style>
```

I thought maybe WebHost was the problem, but I've been able to insert photos with PHP and HTML (unfortunately NativeScript-Vue doesn't allow HTML).

Comment: How are you writing image with PHP, it is directly to disk assuming PHP runs on the same server?

Comment: @Manoj Yes the PHP script is located in the same server

Comment: Is this the URL of PHP script by any chance `https://ipaccovoiturage.000webhostapp.com/pictures`? If it's the folder, you have to call a PHP script which can write the uploaded image to specific path.

Comment: @Manoj Do I have to send the Image Path to PHP, or the whole Image (and if so, how do I do that?)

Comment: @Manoj Also my  PHP script is located in: https://ipaccovoiturage.000webhostapp.com/myScript.php

Comment: All that is up to what you have in your PHP code, it should be able to read the uploaded file in request and move it to the folder you want to.

Comment: @Manoj Alright, I'll try to make this work somehow. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in plain javascript. I was working on it for a couple of days. @Manoj answers didn't work for me. I had to use multipartUpload since I am sending an additional parameter.

Make sure to match the name parameter (fileToUpload) in the request to the name expected by your service. "file" in my case.

The service API signature looks like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(string listingId, IFormFile file)
```

My request:

```
const request = {
    url: "yoururl",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        "Authorization": token
    },
    description: `Uploading image ${name}`,
    androidAutoDeleteAfterUpload: true,
    androidNotificationTitle: "HTTP background"
};

const params = [
        {
            name: "listingId",
            value: 2
        },
        {
            name: "file", // Note it is not fileToUpload but file instead.
            filename: path,
            mimeType: "image/jpeg"
        }
    ];
    const task = session.multipartUpload(params, request);
```

I hope it helps. By the way both Content-Type multipart/form-data and application/octet-stream work for me, but I use multipart/form-data for consistency